# Can I apply for UK tourist visa from France if I have a Schengen visa issued by Germany?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, germany

I want to visit UK. I have a Schengen visa issued by Germany. Can I apply  UK tourist visa from France? Or do I have to apply from Germany?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: And where are you right now, in France, Germany or elsewhere?

Comment: If you can apply from Germany, then you should be able to apply from France as well. Question is whether it's possible to apply at all while on a Schengen visa. In this case, I think it is. In the other direction (UK visitor applying for a Schengen visa), it isn't.

Comment: It's a good question.  Nationality of the applicant is not relevant for visitor applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply for a UK Visitor (general) visa in any country that you entered legally.  The only stipulation is that you must remain outside of the UK while your application is being processed and there must be a designated issuing post in that country.  Nationality of the applicant does not matter.

This is covered in Paragraph 28 of the rules...

> An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom
>   and Islands at the time of the application. An applicant for an entry
>   clearance who is seeking entry as a visitor must apply to a post
>   designated by the Secretary of State to accept applications for entry
>   clearance for that purpose and from that category of applicant.
>   Subject to paragraph 28A, any other application must be made to the
>   post in the country or territory where the applicant is living which
>   has been designated by the Secretary of State to accept applications
>   for entry clearance for that purpose and from that category of
>   applicant. Where there is no such post the applicant must apply to the
>   appropriate designated post outside the country or territory where he
>   is living.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/420595/Immigration_rules_part_1_master_20150406_v1_final.pdf

All UK posts in the Schengen zone (including Visa Facilitation Centres) are designated to accept visitor applications (but they sent to and are processed at the hub in Paris).  So France is ok and the answer to your question is YES.  See Paragraph 41 of the rules for information on specific requirements.

From a practical viewpoint as someone travelling in Europe, you may want to consider if you have all the needed evidence to hand and can do with not having your passport for a while.  If not, then it may be better to wait.